# Golang: reflect.DeepEqual returns unexpected false

Tags: go, testing, tdd

I have the following code and code test below and for some reason the deepEqual is returning a false and failing the test. Now from reading the doco on this I would expect this to pass with a true for something so simple? Any points would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
// customer.go
type Customer struct {
    customerID int
    domains []string
    names []string
}
func NewCustomer(customerID int, domains []string, names []string) *Customer{
    return &Customer{
        customerID: customerID,
        domains: domains,
        names:names,
    }
}
```

```
// customer_test.go
func TestNewCustomer(t *testing.T) {
    expected := &Customer{123,
        []string{},
        []string{},
    }

    got := NewCustomer(123, []string{}, []string{})

    if got.customerID != expected.customerID {
        t.Errorf("Got: %v, expected: %v", got.customerID, expected.customerID)
    }

    if reflect.DeepEqual(got, expected) {
        t.Errorf("Got: %v, expected: %v", got, expected)
    }
}
```

output:

```
Got: &{123 [] []}, expected: &{123 [] []}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reflect.DeepEqual()` returns `true` as expected, that's why your `t.Errorf()` is called.

You want the test to fail if they are **not** equal. You simply have to negate the condition:

```
if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, expected) {
    t.Errorf("Got: %v, expected: %v", got, expected)
}
```